# Read a text file and store each line in a variable using perl

Tags: perl

I have a text file (sample.txt) with some data. I want to read the text file and store each line in an array or a variable.

sample.txt

```
ab1234
str:abcd
pq4567
```

How can i store each of these lines in an array or a variable using perl script.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy. We open the file, push each line in the file to an array after you `chomped` `\n` (newline characters) and to test it, we print the array.
Here `$_` is each of the lines read from file where `@lines` will store each of `$_` in an array.

```
use strict;
use warnings

my $file = "sample.txt";
open(my $fh, "<", "sample.txt") or die "Unable to open < sample.txt: $!";
my @lines;
while (<$fh>) {
chomp $_;
push (@lines, $_);
}
close $fh or die "Unable to open $file: $!";
print @lines;
```

an even easier method  is to just store the content to array.

```
use strict;
use warnings

my $file = "sample.txt";
open(my $fh, "<", "sample.txt") or die "Unable to open < sample.txt: $!";
my @lines = <$fh>;
chomp(@lines);
print @lines;
```

Comment: Note that this will keep the newline at the end of each line. A `chop` or `chomp` is often useful.

Comment: If you know that lexical filehandles and the three-arg version of `open()` is "the better method to open a file", then why don't you use it for all of your example code?

Answer (score 0):

```
# open the file
open my $fh, '<', 'sample.txt'
  or die "Could not open sample.txt: $!";

# Read the file into an array
my @lines = <$fh>;

# Optionally, remove newlines from all lines in the array
chomp(@lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use CPAN modules, then `Tie::File` is there for your help.
Using this module you can modify, add or delete the contents in the file.

below is the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;

my @contents=();

tie @contents, 'Tie::File','sample.txt' or die "Not able to Tie sample.txt\n";

my $count=1;
foreach (@contents)
{
    print "line $count:$_\n";
    $count++;
}

untie @contents;
```

output:

```
line 1: ab1234
line 2: str:abcd
line 3: pq4567
```